# how to get mailbox expiration date using cmdlets 2007?

Tags: exchange-2007, exchange-2013, powershell

i wants to know which cmdlets used to find the expiration date of mailbox in exchange server 2007. I have a cmdlets that gives mailbox expiration date for exchange server 2013. Is there any equivalent cmdltes available for exchange server 2007.
cmdlets for exchange server 2013

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * –Properties Name, EmailAddress, AccountExpirationDate, GivenName |   select Name, EmailAddress, AccountExpirationDate, GivenName | where{$_.AccountExpirationDate –ne $null}
```